# PhpStorm inspector does not recognize the colon symbol in XML attribute

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, vue.js, webstorm

I am trying to make a syntax highlighting for Vue.js. But it does not work with `:attr`, at all.

[image]

`(?!v-for)(v-.*)` and `@[a-z].*` works as well. But this does not work even like

[image]

`\` automatically deleted after saving

Comment: If I try to manually inject JavaScript context into value of `:disabled` attribute .. IDE will create rule without `:` .. so it will apply to ordinary `disabled` attributes as well...  1) http://postimg.org/image/s0j4jt54n/ 2) http://postimg.org/image/hrqndzh2v/

Comment: I also thought that maybe I can just clone existing `xml: */@on.*` rule and adjust it accordingly .. but it does not work (cloned entry looses everything after accepting changes in Settings screen)

Comment: If anything -- consider creating a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23{Language Injection} (but check for existing tickets first). If you create it -- please refer ticket ID here and mention me via `@username`

Comment: @LazyOne `.*` worked fine, but of course for every attribute. Thank you for explaining in more detail. This is what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need anymore. Now it officialy supported in new phpstorm/webstorm.